# Populating an options select menu from MySql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to populate a second options select menu based on a selection in another menu. The problem is, I cannot get the jQuery to execute it.
Here is my code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#add_subject").change(function()
{
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc.add.content.populate.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#add_content").html(html);
        } 
    }); 
});
});
</script>
</head>

<div class="grid_10">
    <div class="box round first">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="block"> 
        <form method="post">
            <table class="form">
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select id="add_subject" name="add_subject">
                            <option value="1">first option</option>                           
                        </select>
                        <select id="add_content" name="add_content">
                        </select>
                   </td>
                </tr>                
             </table>
        </form>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my inc.add.content.populate.php file

```
<?php
require_once(BASEDIR.'includes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'inc.functions.php');

if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
global $mysqli;

if($query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT naslov,vsebine_id FROM table_vsebine WHERE predmet_id=?")){
    $query->bind_param('i',$id);
    if($query->execute()){
        $query->bind_result($naslov,$vsebine_id);
        $query->store_result();

        while($row = $query->fetch()){
        echo '<option value="'.$vsebine_id.'">'.$naslov.'</option>';
        }
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your Javascript console? Or errors in your PHP log?

Comment: No errors whatsoever :(
The javascript function works and replaces the options (if i put $("#add_content").html('<option>bbb</option>'); after the dataString variable, I think something is wrong with the .ajax part)

Comment: if you `console.log(html)` in the success method, what do you get?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the require_once statement, actually the BASEDIR. The BASEDIR is defined in the main index.php file, why wont it get recognised in this file?

Comment: because nothing calls your index file in this case to actually define that. PHP is a stateless language. So unless you define something on the active connection, it will not be defined.

Comment: Mind if I throw this in an answer and you can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a constant that was defined elsewhere in your application

PHP is a stateless language, meaning that each connection gets treated differently.

You will probably want to either define the `BASEDIR`, and probably `DIRECTOR_SEPARATOR` in the file you are using them in. Or, if you are using them in multiple files, you can put all of your defines into a single file and include it whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly running `inc.add.content.populate.php` file and `BASEDIR` is defined in your `index.php` so, in this case, your `BASEDIR` is not defined in this script because `index.php` is not executed in this ajax call.

If you define all of your `constant` in a separate file, say, `constants.php` and just use/include it in `index.php` and also in `inc.add.content.populate.php` then it could be done easily, like

```
require_once('path/to/file/constants.php');
require_once(BASEDIR.'includes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'inc.functions.php');
// ...
```